# Creating graphics control in WPF and integrate to other winform application

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

We have a existing applicaiton in winform .net. It has a form which displays a kind of flow chart diagram. Now we want to create a control which has enhanced graphics to display this flow chart. With my limited knowledge on wpf, is it possible -

1. Create a graphics control in wpf which is display the flow chart
2. Integrate this control to exisiting winform application.
3. The diagram should have user interation, like moving blocks in the chart.
4. Is wpf a better solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to integrate WPF into Winform [tutorial here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms).

With regards to actually creating a flow chart and making it interact with your existing Winform can have its own challenges. Keep in mind that WPF is a very powerful tool so you should consider moving over to WPF if you have the man-power and resources to do so.

Also look into the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) design pattern for WPF and you cannot go wrong. Good luck.